# using onclick to call assign a php variable always assigns the second onclick

Tags: php, onclick

I have these onclicks that when clicked changes the value of $table which has been instantiated in the head  `$table = 'dust_devils';`  to the default  of dust_devils

```
<span onclick = <?php $table = 'dust_devils';?>> Dust Devils </span> <br />
<span onclick = <?php $table = 'fire_giants';?>> Fire Giants </span>
```

these connect to my function  `function getLog($table){...}`  in order to get a specific table from my database.

However when my page loads it automatically loads to the last assignment. In this case it's fire_giants.

Anyone know what's wrong here?

---

EDIT: Besides the fact that serverside + client side doesnt interact. There is a default value that it isn't following declared SERVER side.

Comment: If you look at the output of this, you will find it is `<span onclick = > Dust Devils </span> <br /><span onclick = > Fire Giants </span>` - try calling `echo` once in a while. Please also remember that PHP is server side and JS is client side, and that JS strings need quotes too... Please explain what you expect to happen along with output examples.

Comment: I actually took out the quotes thinking that was the problem. Where should I put my echo? I just want it to reassign `$table` to the other table names. Ie when I click on the span, my <table> is populated with the values in the table in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do something like this.

```
<span onClick = "load('FireGiants')">Fire Giants</span>
```

With Jquery/javascript whatever

```
<script>
function load(type){
  $.AJAX({
      Method:"post",
      url:"getTable.php",
      data : {"type" : type},
      success : function(d) {
          $('#AREATOAPPEND').append(d);
      }
  });

}
</script>
```

With a php page that just does the rendering for the click function.

```
 <?php
 $type = $_POST['type'];

 //Do Table Generation

 echo 'Table for this type';
 ?>
```

Or you could just pass the entire structure to the table via JSON or something and render it client side on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting that all of the PHP is evaluated and executed on the server, before the page is sent to the browser.

If you view the HTML source in your browser (normally by pressing Ctrl+U), you will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: The problem is normally, when I call or change stuff 'client side' usually it does work. It also doesnt change the fact that the variable is assigned before the page loaded, and called when the page loads so it should still start with 'dust_devils'.

Comment: I can assure you, it doesn't work.  Javascript cannot magically interact with PHP, other than indirectly via AJAX (or similar).

Comment: Normally I use json or echo. I think I've been assuming it does work from being able to call functions via onclicks.

Again, regardless of whether it interacts. My statement still stands there is a default value declared in the server side that it's going against.

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: On the server, you're first assigning one value to `$table`, and then assigning another.  So from then onwards, the second value holds.

Comment: So the php ignores the onclick right? The only way to have it not ignore the onclick  is to use AJAX, json etc?

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: PHP ignores anything outside the `<?php ?>` tags.